# Visual Studio Community 2022: mscoreei.dll could not be loaded

Tags: visual-studio, windows-11, .net-framework, parallels, visual-studio-2022

I've become suddenly unable to use Visual Studio Community due to the error in the screenshot. It comes up a lot and makes the IDE completely unusable. The error comes after I load up my solution.

My setup consists of Visual Studio Community 2022 running on an M1 MacBook through Parallels with Windows 11.

The error says mscoreei.dll cannot be loaded. The file is in fact there, but I guess it's either wrong or has the wrong permissions. Possibly the file that is there does not match the ARM version of Windows I'm running. However, everything has been working fine so far. The error keeps popping up every couple of seconds.

I suspect the issue has happened due to either a Visual Studio update or a Windows Update.

So far I've tried to repair .Net, repair Windows and repair Visual Studio, but unfortunately that has brought no change. I've also tried to install everything from scratch with a completely new Virtual Machine two times, again the same thing happens.

[image: screenshot showing the mscoreei.dll error]

Comment: .NET Framework 4 isn't compatible with Windows 11 on ARM.  **It's a 64-bit x86 only binary.** Did your setup recently change?  Honestly, I don't see how this ever could have worked, unless you are running a [preview build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-on-arm-devices?view=vs-2022) of Visual Studio 2022.  Even if that is the case, attempting to use a .NET Framework 4.0 assembly, still wouldn't work on Windows on ARM install.

Comment: When you address some of my confusion be sure you [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to solve this issue by upgrading to .Net 4.8, which fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

That DLL have relation with `.NET` Framework 4 so, [try to install it](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net40) from the official `.NET` site and try if now recognizes it. At least, this installer is for both x86 and x64 environments.

Note that this version is no longer supported by Microsoft Corp.

Comment: If installer says "is already a part of this operating system", press WIN+R and execute "optionalfeatures"; uncheck ".NET 4", reboot and repeat, this time enabling it.
That will do the trick.